# Xamarin iOS - where does application initialization code go?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, initialization

I'm building a Xamarin iOS app which uses Ninject (a DI framework). I'm wondering where do I put the code that loads the modules and does the initialization of my application classes?

- Would I put it in the application's delegate class?
- In the `Main.cs` class?
- In my first ViewController class (which is a menu view so it doesn't really make sens)?

What's the best practice? I can't seem to find it on google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the fact the `UIApplication` runloop is created/initialized during the UIApplication construction, I would avoid using the `Main` entry point as global app initiation point as the app's runloop is not available. Calling any iOS framework members during this phase can led to strange app behavior, crashes, file corruption, etc..

Also any initialization code that hangs (delays) the app at this point will cause the OS to kill your process and any external crash reporting will not happen. Apple's crash reports will be very generic SIGABRT reports.

The `UIApplicationDelegate` is also created during the UIApplication construction and the `FinishedLaunching` (`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`) delegate method is messaged after the `UIApplication`, its runloop and `UIApplicationDelegate` are constructed, but before the `UIWindow` and root VC are, thus making it the preferred delegate override.

Comment: Ah ok, that also makes sens. I'll changed the accepted answer

Comment: I will say that I have never seen a problem of this sort with dependency registration, as normally all one is doing here is populating a dictionary<string, type>, but @SushiHangover's commentary is well-taken and I think points to a more generally safe way.

Comment: @MarkLarter Its "not" that you can not use `Main`, but you need to be careful of what you are doing there. As you say populating a C# dictionary is fairly clean, but when you start loading DI modules, performing initializations, etc... that code should not be running in Main

Answer (score 1):

In the `FinishedLaunching` method of `AppDelegate.cs` is one place for sure, but in several apps I have needed dependencies resolved prior because they are used in `FinishedLaunching`, so I have become accustomed to put this in the `Main` method of App.cs instead.

Here is a very simple example for an app that used `Splat.Locator` for rudimentary DI:

```
public class App
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Register platform-specific dependencies.
        RegisterDependencies();

        // Launch UI.
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }

    private static void RegisterDependencies()
    {
        // Akavache secure cache encryption provider.
        var encryptionProvider = new KeystoreBackedEncryptionProvider(Akavache.BlobCache.TaskpoolScheduler, CacheManager.AppName, CacheManager.CacheName);
        Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant(encryptionProvider, typeof(Akavache.IEncryptionProvider));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok yeah that makes sens. `AppDelegate` could be changed for another class and its responsibility is to handle application events, not load app dependencies. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`AppDelegate` is usually the place you would put any app startup code